# validating form login input using database data c#

Tags: c#, database, forms, authentication

I want to validate form input data using a database as data source. I have the following function which runs but when I input wrong or corect data it throws an error.

```
private void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (txtPassword.Text != "" && txtUsername.Text != "")
    {
        string queryText =
            "SELECT Count(*) FROM dbo.ClientLogin" +
            "WHERE ClientUserName = @uername AND ClientPassword = @password";

        SqlConnection scon = new SqlConnection(
            "Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=Clients;Integrated Security=True");
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(queryText, scon);
        scon.Open();
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", txtUsername.Text);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", txtPassword.Text);
        string result= Convert.ToString(command.ExecuteScalar());
        if (result.Length > 0)
        {
            frmMenu frmMenu = new frmMenu();
            frmMenu.ShowDialog();
        }
        else
            MessageBox.Show("User not found");
    }
    else
        MessageBox.Show("Enter username & password");
}
```

The error is:

> SqlException was unhandled

for statement:

```
string result = Convert.ToString(command.ExecuteScalar());
```

Any help on fixing this error will be appreciated. :)

Comment: You've got misspeling in parameter: `@uername`. Check the query code.

Comment: I fixed the misspelled word but it still gives the same error

Comment: So look for the inner exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If no user is found, then a count of `0` will be returned. Since you convert this `int` result into the string `"0"` its length will be `1`. `"0".Length == 1`!

Since an `int` result is returned by `ExecuteScalar()` (statically typed as `object`), cast it to an `int` instead of converting it to a `string`:

```
int result = (int)command.ExecuteScalar();
if (result > 0) {
   ...
} else {
   ...
}
```

Also, as  Volodymyr Melnychuk has already pointed out, the parameter in the SQL string should be 
called `@username` instead of `@uername`.

---

You are missing a space between `dbo.ClientLogin` and `WHERE`.

Replace

```
string queryText = "... dbo.ClientLogin" +
    "WHERE ...";
```

by

```
//                 see the space here  v
string queryText = "... dbo.ClientLogin " +
    "WHERE ...";
```

Other possible reasons: The table name is incorrect, the table is not in the `dbo` schema, a column name is incorrect, you don't have the required access rights.

Comment: I have done as you and @ Volodymyr Melnychuk suggested but it still gives an error

Comment: Ya actually I didnt put a space in between table name and WHERE, it works now, thanks for both your help